# Exchange 2016 on-premise application access

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have implemented an application which accesses calendars in an Office 356 E3 tenant. I've used the `client_credentials` flow and obtained Admin Consent. So far everything seems to work as expected.

Now I have a customer how wants to use my application with an Exchange 2016 on-premise setup. Is there a way to use the same application in this setup as well? Or do I have to implement a new application using EWS?

Answer (score 1):

The graph API is not available on on-prem Exchange, so yes, you have to replace the graph API code with EWS code.

Depending on your use case, it is probably possible to abstract it such that your application can use either one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. In my on-premise setup the outlook rest api is available. I was hoping, that I could use the same application (which supports graph and outlook api). So I will have to implement EWS and impersonation?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue. 
You can change from Office365 Api to the MsGraph Api which supports many of the same features as the Office365 Api does. Your on premise customer needs to put his Exchange servers into hybrit mode for this. MS explained the necessary steps [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/09/26/on-premises-architectural-requirements-for-the-rest-api/). 
The only problem we had is that you cant subscribe onto on premise calendars.

Here is the MsGraph Api doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

You can also consider switching from Office365 to MsGraph entirely as this should also work for you Office365 customers. As I understand it MS is gonna expand the MsGraph Api in the future giving us a single point of contact for interaction with the Office suite and authentication.

@Marc LaFleur pls correct me if I'm wrong on this